# Error opening EPS in GIMP 2.8

Tags: gimp, eps

I'm attempting to import an EPS file into GIMP, but it fails. I'm running v2.8.19, and I've installed Ghostscript 9.14 (I think that's the version).

I've also gone through setting up the System Variable and verified the path. I did notice there were 2 versions of the 64-bit GS file, one ending with "c" and the other not. Neither `exe` file works.

Any thoughts on fixing this aside from reverting to an earlier version of GIMP?

The error reads as follows (I yellowed out part of the path, but there are no spaces or illegal characters):

[image]

Comment: I am unsure what your question is and if it relates to graphic design. What is it exactly you are asking of us?

Comment: I use GIMP for graphic design/editing. I attempted to import an EPS file and received an error. I asked if anyone knew how to rectify the error. I found this Stackoverflow forum because people have been asking questions on GIMP, so I thought this would be a good resource for errors when using GIMP. Sorry, thought it was pretty clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to install [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/),

> Ghostscript is a suite of software based on an interpreter for Adobe Systems' PostScript and Portable Document Format (PDF) page description languages. Its main purposes are the rasterization or rendering of such page description language files, for the display or printing of document pages, and the conversion between PostScript and PDF files.

*Source:* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript

**Edit**:

Oh just noticed you've already installed Ghostscript. I'm not too sure then. A quick search found: http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/15141-gimp-2-8-2-eps-support which has

> Clarification:
>
> On Windows versions of GIMP (v2.8.2 and later) it no longer uses the GS_PROG variable to detect and load GhostScript, it uses a DLL instead.
>
> If you have a 64 bit Windows operating system, 64 bit Windows version of GIMP 2.8.2 or higher, and 64 bit Windows version of GhostScript 9.06 or higher (do not try to mix 64 bit and 32 bit versions!) then try this:
>
> 1) Back up the libgs-8.dll file in the GIMP bin folder.
>
> 2) Copy the gsdll64.dll file from the GhostScript bin folder to the GIMP folder.
>
> 3) Rename the copied gsdll64.dll file to libgs-8.dll.
>
> 4) Restart GIMP.

If you're on Windows64 that might help you. If not you should probably ask over there, or on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com), since this is more of a technical issue.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I'll try that and check this as the answer if it works. I appreciate you reading through the question and providing good feedback.

Comment: Ryan, I finally got to try your answer and it worked! ...Brilliant. THANK YOU!